# In an Eclipse plugin, what's the right way to get the .class file that corresponds to the selected java file?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin.  I'm looking for the right way to get a selected java file and find it's corresponding .class file.

The way I'm doing it now works for a standard Eclipse java project, but seems less than elegant: I call IJavaProject#getOutputLocation and combine that with the path to the selected file.  Then I just change .java to .class.

Here's the code for the method that translates from the incoming selection to a path:

```
def selection_to_path selection
    path = selection.get_paths.first

    output_location = path.get_first_segment.get_output_location
    root = org.eclipse.core.resources::ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().get_root
    folder = root.get_folder output_location
    folder.get_location.to_s

    path_to_file_as_string = path.get_last_segment.get_path.to_s
    path_to_file_as_string[/\.java$/] = ".class"
    path_elements_of_java_file = path_to_file_as_string.split("/")[3..-1]

    all_elements = folder.get_location.to_s.split("/") + path_elements_of_java_file

    File.join(all_elements)
  end
```

This works, but I suspect it fails often enough that it's not the right thing to do.  In particular, the documentation for getOutputLocation says that my assumptions about class file locations are too simplistic.

So what's the right way to do this?

I don't need this to work all of the time.  Certainly there will be many cases where a .java file doesn't have a corresponding .class file (compilation errors, no automatic builds, whatever).  I don't care about those; I just want to know if there is a class file, what is its full path?

Comment: Just curious...is the code above pseudo code, or are you writing your plugin in a different language?  If so, what is it?

Comment: It's jruby.  I'm playing with jruby plugins - the full thing is on github at https://github.com/banshee/JrubyEclipsePlugin .  The interesting part is that you can modify your plugins on the fly with jruby, no need to have a full plugin development environment for simple tasks.  It's still pretty rough, but it's working and I'm using to get stuff done.

Comment: Interesting...do you have a way to do a PDE build for JRuby plugins?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  If you're building a plugin that wants to use jruby(and using PDE to build it), just include jruby.jar; there's really nothing else to do.  (That's a different thing than what I'm doing; my plugin has a menu option to reload the ruby file, so you can make a change to the ruby file, hit reload, and see your changes without ever involving PDE.)

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is that unless you do something tricky, PDE build expects that all files that it will compile are Java files.  I don't know much about Ruby and JRuby, but I think that the reason why you can get around this restriction is that Ruby is an interpreted language.  And so the Ruby files do not need to be compiled.

Comment: Andrew - check out how jruby works - https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GeneratingJavaClasses is particularly interesting.  But it's not really useful to say that PDE expects all files to be Java - the real deal is bytecode for the jvm, not Java-the-language.  You can write plugins in probably dozens of languages that output something useful on a jvm.  Java is just one of them.

Comment: Ah, Andrew, just looked at your profile - I think I'm answering the wrong question given that you work on things like Groovy.  I think the "tricky" bit is that jruby has a jruby > java compiler.  You can build a jruby file using that, and you end up with a java class with Jruby embedded in it.  It means you don't really have to tell PDE anything at all - it sees a java file, and you're all done.  That java class, though, is a very simple ruby method that just imports another ruby script, and that second script is the thing that does all the real work - anything you want.

Comment: But to most people who use jruby, that doesn't count as tricky - it's just the way to do things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3808/discussion-between-andrew-eisenberg-and-james-moore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method, which directly finds the corresponding class file resource. The proper way to get the corresponding output folder is to:

- Convert the selection to `IJavaElement`, most probably `ICompilationUnit` (.java files)
- Find the corresponding `IPackageFragmentRoot` (the source folder)
- Find the resolved `IClasspathEntry`
- Find the output location using `IClasspathEntry.getOutputLocation()` or the `IJavaProject.getOutputLocation()` method, depending on whether the classpath entry has separate output location.
- Construct the path to the classpath based on the `ICompilationUnit`'s package

The class file may or may not exist depending on whether the project has been build, whether there are build path errors, etc. So, there are additional heuristics, which you need to use to determine whether the result of the above algorithm will be usable.